# Can Photoshop be Used as a 3D Modeling Program for Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, photoshop

I was looking in to Photoshop cs6 extended recently, and I realized that 3D modeling can be done in there.  Currently, I am trying to learn game design with unity3d and I was wondering if it is possible to import models from Photoshop into unity3d.  Right now I do all of my 3D modeling work in blender.  What are the capabilities of Photoshop and 3D modeling exactly?  Would it be possible, or even smart, to import models made in Photoshop to Unity3d?  If it is possible to make a 2d drawing into a 3d model using these tools would it be a smart thing to try to do?  Or would it be better to just create a 3D model from scratch in blender.  Sorry for all of these questions; I am new to Photoshop and would just like to know what is possible and if using it in this fashion would be a good idea.  Would it be good to change my workflow to do modeling in Photoshop.  If I am confused about anything, please correct me.  I would also like to know if the meshes created in Photoshop are low-poly because I would like to use them in a mobile game.  Would the model and all of it's parts created there import well into Unity3d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a fast research on Photoshop's documentation and found that it support exporting to Collada(DAE) and Wavefront(OBJ) 3D formats so your answer could be YES, you can.

But, OBJ doesn't support animation (you can check the specification [here](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/obj/) if you want, it has a long time that I don't work with OBJ)

Despite Collada's .dae support animation it never worked properly when I tried to import on Unity.

You can also import your models and animate them into Unity itself but why don't choose for a professional 3D tool instead of a native 2D tool adapted to support 3D and still very limited on 3D features?

Comment: One quick question, however, before I investigate further, will the materials also import well?  Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: The reason I would like to do this is the quick capability to convert from 2D to 3D.  So, I would start with a 2D object in Photoshop, bring it to 3D and then import it into blender.  From there, I can continue my work.  I believe that it may be valuable if I can start from 2D and go to 3D.  I could, for example, create a character, convert it to 3D, and then texture it, etc. in Blender. Would this be a good workflow?

Comment: I've never did it before so I can't say "Yes it is a good pipeline" or "No it will be a pain in the a**". I tend to believe in the second one cause for games you need to pay attention on mesh edge loops and vertex count and usually generators don't do a good job on it so you probably would need retopo and a lot of work to adjust your model (but could be wrong, is a mater of try and see).